Why does my wsl take more space than what it says in the terminal
I ran du -h --max-depth=1 at home and it returns 4.7G however, installed apps in Windows settings say that it's taking about 28.9 GB. I haven't installed any huge packages as dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size}\n' | awk '{total += $1} END {print total/1024/1024 " GB"}' returns 3.23621 GB

Difference between the amount of space the virtual environment is using and the physical disk space on the host. I am fairly sure that the default size of a WSL VHDD is about 28GB. WSL GitHub probably has more information.
